# .NET CLR and CPU architecture dependency

Tags: .net, jvm, cross-platform, clr, virtual-machine

Why there are seperate versions of Windows(Windows 8 and RT) for different CPU architectures(x86 and ARM) when the code is executed on a virtual machine that could translate the bytecode into architecture specific instructions?
For example Android is based on Java which executes on the JVM and that's why there are smartphones with ARM and Intel CPU with full compatibility. What are the reasons Microsoft isn't doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why there are seperate versions of Windows(Windows 8 and RT) for different CPU architectures(x86 and ARM) when the code is executed on a virtual machine that could translate the bytecode into architecture specific instructions?

On the x86 version of Windows 8, not all code is executed on a virtual machine.  Desktop mode applications run as full x86 or x64 processes.

That being said, I believe part of the goal here was to purposely limit and change the API on these devices, and not provide full support.  There are many types and methods in the .NET framework which were designed for "desktop" or "server" applications.  While it would (theoretically) be possible to make these work by translating to the native instructions, the overall architecture is not appropriate for these devices.

Providing a new API and a separate "framework" specific to Windows 8 (and Windows Phone 8) allows the framework to restrict itself to appropriate APIs - either appropriate in terms of latency (no synchronous methods), power consumption, or other similar concerns.

That being said, the Portable Class Libraries do try to make the bridge here for most "pure" logic assemblies.  Using the PCL allows you to write a single assembly that is usable on Windows 8, both desktop and RT, phone, etc.